# problem on running Chainlink node

Tags: chainlink, docker, linux

I am currently running a linux aarch64 nvidia jetson tx2 machine. I try to run my chainlink node with docker using this [docs here](https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-nodes/v1/running-a-chainlink-node).

In the line of `cd ~/.chainlink-nvidia && sudo docker run --platform linux/x86_64/v8 --name chainlink -v ~/.chainlink-nvidia:/chainlink -it -p 6688:6688 --add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway smartcontract/chainlink:2.3.0 node -config /chainlink/config.toml -secrets /chainlink/secrets.toml start`

I encounter an error saying `exec /usr/local/bin/chainlink: exec format error`.
Apparently the container is created but when trying to run `sudo docker run chainlink` it then says `docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for chainlink, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.`

How can I run my chainlink docker on my linux machine? Please help.

Comment: Okay, so I am able to pull the docker container using linux/arm64 rather than linux/x86_64/v8 but when I try to start docker this time it wont start. And I check the logs for it there is an error saying "exec /usr/local/bin/chainlink: no such file or directory". Why didnt I get that? And somehow my intel devices able to execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you also struggle with pulling chainlink to docker due to different chip architecture, someone rebuild it compatible for arm64. You can find it on docker hub, alternatively on this [link](https://hub.docker.com/r/dkotelkin/chainlink-arm)